# Is it possible to sync and recover a current profile in Pokemon Y and X?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

My wife and I want to play Pokemon with different profiles, but the game has just one profile. I did some research and until now the only way to have another profile is to buy another game.

I would like to know if there is a way to sync my profile online, then delete my current profile and start a new game. And in the future recover my old profile, and continue my previous game.

Comment: I have never come across a way of doing this, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for some reason GameFreaks has only ever made Pokemon games allow one save file, with no methods of backup, since Pokemon R/G in 1997

Comment: The reason is down to the severe memory limitations in the original cartridges - the continuation of this legacy is part tradition/habit, part money making (siblings need a console and a game each, can't have a save each on just one game)

Comment: And also in part to stop save scumming regarding legendaries - What? you want that legendary? sure thing, let me just start a new game and catch it for you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's impossible, because your game cartridge takes priority over sync'd profile. I believe it only sync's a small portion of save anyway and even if you did manage to do it, it would be extremely risky.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. But, if you are patient, you can get the Pokebank, which allows you to move Pokemon to it, restart your game, and get them back. That only works if it is your Pokemon you are worried about.